# Normalising angle between negative y-axis and vector

Tags: c++, math, angle, atan2

[image]

From picture: I have to calculate alpha, defined as the angle between the lines that connects two points and the y-axis, with a range 0 to 180 in the direction that can be seen in the image, and with a range of 0 to -180 in the opposite (arrow pointing from current starting point to finger1).

`(atan2((x1 - x), (y - y1)) * 180/ M_PI );`

I managed to do so with this formula, simply inverting x and y reference in atan2 function, but this works only when the first point (x,y) is on "bottom-right" in respect of the second.
In that case I get the exact expected result. In all the others obviously I get wrong values. How could I normalise this to get always the same values?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - although the question tags [c++] - it appears to be solely about the maths, not about any software implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Definition:

- we have two points P1 and P2 (Finger1, Finger2)
- we introduce a vector v: P2 - P1

Calculate the slope m of v:

```
m = v.y / v.x;
```

- if m < 0: slope decreases from upper left to bottom right
- if m > 0: slope increases from bottom left to upper right
- if m == 0: constant
- if v.x == 0: m is undefined

Since the value of the slope is the same (sign differs) for the inverted vector v (-v), we can use the absolute value of m.

The angle θ between the positive x-axis and the vector v:

```
theta = atan(abs(m));
```

The angle α is:

```
alpha = M_PI_2 - theta;
```

That is basically what `atan2` does, but `atan2` gives you a value in the range [-π, π]. With the above code, we get a value in the range [0, π / 2].

It doesn't matter if the y-axis is presented on the screen from top to bottom or vice versa. The math is the same. But that implies, that you receive your P1 and P2 in the same system. If not, then you have to mirror the points on the x-axis, which is changing the sign of the y-coords of the points.

**The detailed version:**

```
alpha = M_PI_2 - (atan(abs((P2.y - P1.y) / (P2.x - P1.x)))); //radians
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! So, just to understand if I understood correctly, in my case I would need to use
`theta = atan2(abs(x2-x1),abs)y2-y1))`
and then?
`alpha = M_PI_2 - theta`
to rotate it so that it is relative to Y axis? but what about the orientation, given taht we want it to be positive in the clokcwise way? Is this a problem?

Comment: Forget about atan2. We want a value in range [0, pi / 2]. The slope is (dY / dX). You get either a positive or negative value. We want a positive value, that's why we take the absolute value of the slope: abs(dY / dX). Since m = tan(theta) => theta = atan(abs(m)). Now we have the angle between the x-axis and our slope, but you want the other half, that is why we subtract it from 90 degrees, which is pi / 2.

Comment: I've added a detailed version of the calculation.

Comment: I was using atan2 because the problem requires me to give, as a solution, an angle between -179...0....179, with positive range being in the drawn alpha direction

Comment: `atan2` gives you a value in the range [-pi, pi]. But `atan2` is declared as `atan2(double y, double x)`, you switched the x and y coords, why? Because your screen prints the y-axis from top to bottom? The math is the same, no matter how you draw your graph.

Comment: No, i switched x and y because I want the angle not relative to x-axis but to y-axis, was this a stupid thing? Though it works, just it doesn't when the first finger placed on screen (so x1,y1) is above the other